# In a react application ,on a routed page how do you do a browser refresh on a routed page .browser refresh with circular arrow on routed page?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, vite

If you are on a routed and protected page
Domain.com/customer/contact/name  and now u want to do browser refresh with circular button how to achieve this with react router v6 without reloading the entire application .
/customer Home component
/contact/name Name component
How do you refresh the page with react router v6 on a routed page ..
Thanks for your help

Window.location.reload gives 404
Not found error
Whenever in browser I
Put domain.com/customer/contact/name
It gives not found error

I am deploying this app to Apache server. And basename
Is set up as /customer and it render index.html from server

I have tried naviagte(0) as well
I have tried UseEffect, before unload
As well